# Declaring a variable in batch and using it in one line

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, payload

Is it possible to declare a variable and use it in the same line?
For example (this doesn't work):

```
set foo="bar" && echo %foo%
```

to print `bar`.

Comment: Do you want to use it on the command line or in a batch file? That makes a difference

Comment: On the command line, @Paulo Campez's answer works

Comment: `cmd /V:ON /C "set "var=hello" & echo !var!"` (from the answer to the duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set "foo=bar" && call echo %^foo%
```

Comment: ...why does this work? The location of the caret means the `f` is being escaped.

Comment: Is there a way to use this variable to redirect an output ?
For example, I want to write `baz` in the file `bar` like this `set "foo=bar" && call echo baz > %^foo%`

Comment: Upon further investigation, the caret is unnecessary.